# how to Get behaviour of super.onbackpressed() within overrided onbackpressed()

Tags: android

I was tried to go back with confirmation dialog so that i was decided to handle onbackpressed() and then i had put my code for confirm dialog with ok and cancel button for null listener.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Confirmation");
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure want to exit?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    builder.show();   
}
```

It was worked fine but the problem is if i click ok but it should continue for behaviour of super.onbackpressed() otherwise it should be in same activity.

the following code that i had tried.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Confirmation");
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure want to exit?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //super.onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    builder.show();   
}
```

Comment: your code is correct, just dismiss the dialog when clicked cancel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

put finish() to finish your activity in onclick of positive button ...

```
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To call the exact same super method:

```
YourActivity.super.onBackPressed();
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.finish` is not allowed in my activity and `this.finalize` is creapy code.
Android studioprojects wants it to be surrounded with `try`/`catch`.

As `super.onBackPressed()` cannot be called in the `onClick` method of the dialog interface, it is easier to call some private method instead of that.

Let that private method call `super.onBackPressed()` and the result is the same as pressing the back button.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has pressed the back button, you can be pretty sure that they want to exit. However, with that said:

you should implement an `OnClickListener` for your cancel button as well, with the following code:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```html
boolean exit=false;

    ...

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if (exit){
    exit=false;
    super.onBackPressed();
  }else {
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                switch (which) {
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
          exit = true;
          onBackPressed();
          break;
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
          break;
      }
    };
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        builder.setMessage("Are you sure").setPositiveButton("yes", dialogClickListener).setNegativeButton(getResources().getString("no"), dialogClickListener).show();
  }
}
```

With this code in the main activity that contains the fragments, if user presses back on fragment,the app shows the dialog and if user presses 'yes' button, it will come back to call to onBackPressed, but now, it goes back to the last fragment.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5419867/edit) to provide explanation about code.